# How To Call HTML Files From OnitemCLicklistener

Tags: android, android-webview, onitemclicklistener

i want the onitemclicklistener to open HTML pages stored in assets folder and each activity should open in a WebView  , i don't want to have so many activities and so many web views

so here is my onitemclicklistener

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
           if(position==0)
           {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity1.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
           } 
          if(position==1)
           {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
           } 
          if(position==2)
           {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity3.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
           } 


}
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In List item click.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key",position);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In WebviewActivtiy

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web); // webview in activity_web.xml
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv); // initialize once
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
if(pos==0)
{ 
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Have a WebView in your layout xml" ? should i create a webview? please be clear and also where do i insert that oncreate thing?

Comment: @96 you need to have a webview in your xml. If you make an effort by searching how to load html files from assert folder in webview you will find an answer. For every step if you keep asking you will never learn

Comment: @96 you need to start a new activity. pass the position to next activity. In next activity have webview and load html

Comment: @96 check the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html. has an example also.

Comment: adding listivew in webview will also add pinchzoom, functionality in the LISTVIEW also , if i disable pinchzoom, it will also get disabled in the HTML files, which i dont want

Comment: @96 that is why i said start a new activity and load the html to we view in new activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375435/how-to-load-html-file-in-webview-on-onitemclick?noredirect=1#comment30420340_20375435

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with this.

```
private WebView YourWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_web);

    YourWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YourWebView);


    WebSettings wset = webviewMsg.getSettings();
    wset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    YourWebView.loadUrl(YourURL);

     YourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
    }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }
    });
}
```

I hope you help.