# How to load HTML file in webview on onitemclick

Tags: android, html, webview

i have more than 100 html files and i want each file to open on row click in listview and each html file should open in the webview , i tried this code but this is not working, only the webview opens on row click , the html file is not showing up.

```
 package com.Example.apk;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebView extends Activity {

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
        if(pos==0)
        {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work.html");
        }
        else if(pos==1)
        {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work1.html");
        }  
        else if(pos==2)
        {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work2.html");
        } 
        else if(pos==3)
        {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work3.html");
        }  
      // similarly for 4 and 5 and so on.
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you called the loadUrl() in the next activity ? if yes make sure you use a WebViewClient class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the position to next Activity

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivtiy.this,WebViewActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key",position);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
```

Then in WebViewActivity ie activity_webview)

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
WebView web;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
    if(pos==0)
    {
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work.html");
    }
    else if(pos==1)
    {
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work1.html");
    }  
    else if(pos==2)
    {
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work2.html");
    } 
    else if(pos==3)
    {
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/work3.html");
    }  
   ...// similarly for 4 and 5 and so on.
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

xml for WebViewActivity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make an entry for WebViewActivity in Manifest file.

Comment: @96 copy paste the above code in appropriate class and xml and it will work fine

Comment: @96 there is nothing to understand.In `onItemClick` the third param is the position. You pass it to `WebViewActivity`. In `WebViewActivity` get position of item clicked `int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);`. based on position load url ir html from assests fodler
    `if(pos==0)`

Comment: @96 for repition more if else that's all. this is very basic java stuff. nothing difficult not to understand if you know java

Comment: @96 what is the problem can't you add if else also. get a java book and read it

Comment: @96 i see only red lines i can't find what is the error. Pls post the code and the stack trace to help you solve the problem. please post a new question. Try to read stacktrace understand the error and try solving yourself or atleast post it here. posting links or snap shots will not help anybody

Comment: @96 rename your class and import `import android.webkit.WebView;`. this is not error. this is mistake done by you. you have not copied my code. my code never has class by the name WebView. In case new errors post new question coz this is leading to discussion and you don't have enough reputation to chat

Comment: @96 when did you start learning android? Change `public class WebView extends Activity {` to `public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {`. `import android.webkit.WebView` see `android.webkit.WebView` and your class name is also `WebView`. Avoid Naming conflict. I am not commenting any further post a new question

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose use this

```
WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.go_web_view);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, description, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Here "description" is name of string containing data with or without html tags

```
 list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
    String url = m_ArrayList.get(arg2).your_url;
                   Intent myIntent = new     Intent(MainActivtiy.this,AppWebView.class);
                   myIntent.putExtra("key",url);
                   startActivity(myIntent);

      }
     });
```

If you need to render url then try

```
public class AppWebView extends Activity{

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar pBar;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        pBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        String newUrl;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                newUrl = null;
            } else {
                newUrl = extras.getString("url");
            }
        } else {
            newUrl = (String) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable("myJsonStringS");
        }

        Log.d("jitendra", newUrl);

        //SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("booking_detail", 0);
        //String jsonString = sp.getString("jsonString", "");

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.loadUrl(newUrl);

    }
    public void moveToThanksPage()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ThankYou.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
     public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("sagarWeb", url);
                if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                    String[] blah_email = url.split(":");
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{blah_email[1]});
                 //   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "what_ever_you_want_the_subject_to)");
                    Log.d("NOTICE", "Sending Email to: " + blah_email[1] + " with subject: " + "what_ever_you_want_the_subject_to_be");
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
                }
                else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Log.d("Web", "tell");
                    String uri = url;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (url.endsWith("error.jsp")) {
                    Log.d("Web", "Error");
                }
                /*else if (url.contains("thankyou/app")) {

     //===================== USE UNDERMENTIONED COMMENT ON FOR SELF THANKS PAGE ==================//

                    //moveToThanksPage(); 
                }*/
                else
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }




}
```

Comment: can you modify my onitemclicklistener?

Comment: Can U please clarify me that U are getting a url or string or URL/String both ?

Comment: you cant change my WHOLE project for your edit, can you edit my code instead?